# How to refresh a "news" embed based on filter button clicked

Tags: channel-entries, ee3, sorting, filtering

I've got a "news" embed I'm calling from my homepage.  Inside that news listing template it lists 7 articles based on the dates, which could be a mix of 4 different categories.  I'm not using EE categories, it's just a radio button field that is compared to set the styling.  If I need to switch to EE categories I can.

What's the best way to refresh that whole "news" embed section when they click one of the filter buttons?  I need to refresh so it now shows 7 articles with the field type "news_category" equal to say "announcements".

Should I just link to same page but set a segment and pull content based off that segment (/news/announcements), or can I reload this with AJAX or jQuery somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done similar before and ajax is your best bet rather then refresh or link to another page.

Your home page =

```
<h1>Home page<h1>
<!-- Other channel calls -->
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
 <div id="news">
   <select id="switch"> <!-- Use actual category ID values -->
     <option value="01">Option</option>
     <option value="02">Option 2</option>
   </select>
   <div id="news-list">
     {exp:channel:entries 
       limit="7" 
       channel="your_channel"
       }
      {embed = "/news/list"} -- Embed the base 7 articles
     {exp:channel:entries}
   </div>
 </div>
```

Your embed (news/list) =

```
<article>
  <h1><a href="/news/{url_title}>{title}</a></h1>
</article>
```

Javascript =

```
<!-- Assumes you know what you're doing here -->
$('#switch').on('change', function() {
  url = "/ajax/update_news/"+this.value(); <!-- Should render /ajax/update_news/categories_actual_id -->
  $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
      $("#news-list").html(result);
  }});
})
```

/ajax/update_news.html =

```
{exp:channel:entries 
  limit="7" 
  channel="your_channel" 
  category="{segment_3}" {!-- The categories ID --}
  }
  {embed = "/news/list"} -- Embed the base 7 articles
{exp:channel:entries}
```

Embeds can be an expensive include if you have lots of other stuff going on within the page, you could alternately use snippets instead.

**Update**
Your code in comment will never work as your using tags that you've dreamt up. If you don't want to use categories then you'll have to use the search tag

```
{exp:channel:entries search:your_field_name="your_search_term" ...}
```

Have a good read of this page: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html

Comment: awesome, I'll give this a shot and see how it works out.  thank you!

Comment: I have the ajax working but the /ajax/update_news.html doesn't seem to pull the entries I'm trying to filter by.  I think it has to do with what category i'm trying to pull from.  

I'm trying to pull based off a custom radio field I have called "news_category".  Do you think I have to change my channel to use EE categories instead, so when i try to do category="{segment_3}" it works?  Not sure if you can use channel:entries based off a custom radio field.

Comment: Here's my current code... I hardcoded "news_category" just to test and it still doesn't work so that's why I'm gathering custom radio button's won't work like this.

{exp:channel:entries 
channel="news" 
news_category="Tournaments" 
limit="4" 
orderby="news_date" 
disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"}

Comment: Answer updated above